# Adding a delay within a loop

Tags: objective-c, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

Is there any way to add a delay of a fraction of a second to a loop (e.g. A for loop). i.e. I would like a short delay after each iteration.

I know that cocos2d allows you to schedule selecters with a delay. But I am not sure how this could be used in this case.

I also know that sleep is costly and not advisable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hopefully you're not doing this delay on the main (UI) thread, or else your users are going to notice this and not be happy with you.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe `sleep()` can be useful here.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use NSTimers in cocos2d. It will cause troubles if you want to have possibility to pause your game.

If you want to loop some action with fixed delay between iterations, you can freely use scedule:interval: method with needed delay.

```
[self schedule:@selector(methodToScedule) interval:yourDelay]
```

Or if you have to do random delay, you can use sequenses of cocos2d actions. For example

```
- (void) sceduleMethod
{
    // do anything you want

    ccTime randomDuration = // make your random duration
    id delayAction = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: randomDuration];
    id callbackAction = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(scheduleMethod)];
    id sequence = [CCSequenece actionOne: delayAction actionTwo: callbackAction];
    [self runAction: sequence];
}
```

in this case you must call your method only once. Then it will call itself with given delay.

Answer (score 0):

You could use C's sleep function:

```
sleep(seconds);
```

But you could also look at `UITimer`, or possibly a block-based `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method.

See this for more NSObject-based methods: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay

Comment: I am not sure that sleep is the right approach to use as it will suspend any processing all together. I still want the app to do other things just incase.

Comment: Perhaps I can have the method call itself recursively with a delay.

Comment: Is there no way to get the current method to pause but while it is pausing it still handles any other scheduled tasks?

Comment: The only way to get one method to pause without blocking the main UI run loop is to run the method in a background thread. For this, you could use Grand Central Dispatch or one of the built in NSObject-based methods I linked to. You're right, sleep isn't the best way to handle this. Proper threading would be much better.